# How to test plsql function in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plsql

I've a function below

```
create or replace function myFunction()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
  AS $function
  
  declare
    name_val varchar(20);
    place_val varchar(20);
    joindate_val int;
    
 begin
   
   select name,place, min(joindate)
   into name_val, place_val, joindate_val
   from table
   group by name,place
   
   if name_val = 'QWER' then 
     print name_val 
   end if;
  return new;
END;
$function;
```

I want to test this function in redshift, to see what values are coming in declared variables. How I can test it in postgresql only ?

And if the output of aggregate query in function returns more then one records, then do I need to run for loop to iterate before moving values to `if else` condition ? If yes, how it can done ?

Comment: 1) This `print name_val` won't  work. You need to use `RAISE NOTICE` per [Reporting Messages](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE). 2) See [Looping over query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING).  3) Most importantly spend time reading this [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html).

Comment: Oracle PL/SQL or Postgres PL/pgSQL?